# Prevent a block from running until all previous queue items have completed

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Is it possible to add a block to the end of the current queue, and make sure that this block gets called after all existing items in the queue?

The code below doesn't seem to work:

```
- (void)someTaskWillBeDoneOnThisThreadLater {
    // The current scope is a delegate method of a library I'm using, 
    // and unfortunately the required task gets executed after this delegate 
    // method is called.

    // wait for current queue to be done with everything, including the current scope
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
        // After everything is done, then call the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Perform some task on main thread
        });
    });
}
```

**EDIT:**

The following code fixed the problem, but I really don't want to rely on 1 second delay. I rather find a better solution.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        sleep(1);
                        // Perform something on main thread
                    });
                });
```

Comment: What sort of queue are you talking about? That should work for a serial queue, so I guess you've got a concurrent one?

Comment: I'm really not sure, I don't have access to the source code of this framework

Answer (score 2):

I think problem is that you need private queue to get this work. This code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    NSLog(@"FIRST");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"LAST");
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // ...
        });
    });
    sleep(2);
    NSLog(@"SECOND");           
});
```

Gives:

```
2012-07-31 22:57:20.005 Objective-C App[22526:1703] FIRST
2012-07-31 22:57:20.009 Objective-C App[22526:2003] LAST
2012-07-31 22:57:22.010 Objective-C App[22526:1703] SECOND
```

Which isn't what you wanted. Even `dispatch_barrier_async` won't help. But when you use private queue:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("test", 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSLog(@"FIRST");
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSLog(@"LAST");
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // ...
        });
    });
    sleep(2);
    NSLog(@"SECOND");           
});
```

Will give you result you wanted:

```
2012-07-31 23:04:41.882 Objective-C App[22564:1703] FIRST
2012-07-31 23:04:43.887 Objective-C App[22564:1703] SECOND
2012-07-31 23:04:43.889 Objective-C App[22564:1703] LAST
```

As you see "LAST" will be printed at the end and it'll wait 2 seconds until block already on queue is finished.

Comment: This would be perfect if it could be done without the 2 seconds delay

Comment: @Johnnywho: Now I see that you are right with your comment "Even dispatch_barrier_async won't help". The reason is that `dispatch_barrier_async` can only be used on private concurrent queues, otherwise it behaves like `dispatch_async`. Since the OP does not know on which queue the function is called, this won't help much.

Comment: @aryaxt delay isn't a part of this solution! sleep(2) **only simulates** long task to show, that block will wait 2 seconds to complete all previous task on queue

Comment: @MartinR I have reviewed question again, and I agree with you. This method is probably not called from private queue, so my proposition may not work.

Answer (score 0):

From the `dispatch_barrier_async` documentation:

> ... When the barrier block reaches the front of a private concurrent
>   queue, it is not executed immediately. Instead, the queue waits until
>   its currently executing blocks finish executing. At that point, the
>   barrier block executes by itself. Any blocks submitted after the
>   barrier block are not executed until the barrier block completes.

So replacing `dispatch_async` by `dispatch_barrier_async` in your code should do what you want.

**EDIT:**

This works only on private (concurrent) queues, see also the @Johnnywho's answer and the following comments.

I overlooked that part of the documentation, sorry.

Comment: dispatch_barrier did not work, so I guess the queue is a concurrent queue.

Comment: `dispatch_barrier_async` works, but only on private concurrent queues created with `dispatch_queue_create("test", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)`. On the global queue, it behaves like `dispatch_async`. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not clear that the actual problem is as you've described, there is a facility in GCD, available starting in OS X 10.7 or iOS 4.3 to achieve this: [`dispatch_barrier_async()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW57).

Submitting a Block to a queue using this function causes that Block to wait to execute until all previous Blocks have completed; likewise all subsequent Blocks wait for the barrier to complete.

Note that this is only relevant for *concurrent* queues, since the nature of a serial queue is that it will not start executing any Block until all previously submitted Blocks have completed.